# Edit Table of Contents in RMarkdown HTML document

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

In an `RMarkdown HTML` document, is there a way to customize the Table of Contents to include the page numbers for each section and change the underline to dots? Here is my `YAML`:

```
---
title: "Document Title"
subtitle: "Document Subtitle"
author: "My Name"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
output: 
  pagedreport::paged_windmill:
    front_img: Cover Page and Logo/cover.png
    logo: Cover Page and Logo/logo.svg
    logo_to_white: TRUE
    img_to_dark: TRUE
    toc: TRUE
    number_sections: TRUE
knit: pagedown::chrome_print
toc-title: "Table of Contents"
main-color: "#6d1d26"
google-font: FALSE
main-font: "Arial"
header-font: "Arial"
---
```

[image]